# how do i get multiple id's of a particular class?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

This i what i am doing right now.

HTML:

```
 <div class="animateripad" id="ipad">
 <div class="animateripad" id="pong">
```

Javascript:

i am using "document.getElementById" but it only returns one id. i want to get both ids and then use them on if condition

eg

```
if (id=="ipad")
{
do something.
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: It doesn't return an ID, it returns an element.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be elements with in the HTML with the same id. This is where you should be using classes instead. It is not valid HTML

Comment: the classes are same but i have used 2 different ids eg <div class="animateripad" id="ipad"> <div class="animateripad" id="pong"> still wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Id is something unique, so having two DOM elements with the same I'd is wrong. You should use "class" instead, it's semantically correct and you can select several.

Edit: 
document.getElementById returns one Dom element. So you should do:

```
var ping = document.getElementById('ping');
var pong = document.getElementById('pong');
```

If you use getElementById.

If you want to select elements on class you should not use document.getElementById.

Comment: i have edited my question. see if its still wrong. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `getElementById`, if you want to get all elements that have a certain class. Use `getElementsByClassName`:

```
function getIdsForClass(classStr)
{
   var i, all = document.getElementsByClassName(classStr),ids = [];
   for(i=0;i<all.length;i++)
   {
       ids.push(all[i].id);//<-- push id as a string
       //or
       ids.push(all[i]);//<-- push reference to dom element
   }
   return ids;
}
var animateripadIds = getIdsForClass('animateripad');
//if you used ids.push(all[i].id);
animateripadIds[0];//<-- ipad
//if you pushed all[i]
animateripadIds[0].id;//<-- ipad
```

If you want to treat them all, depending on the id:

```
for (var i=0;i<animateripadsIds.length;i++)
{
    switch(animateripadsIds[i].id)
    {
        case 'ipad':
            //do something with animateripadsIds[i]
        break;
        case 'pong':
            //do something else with animateripadsIds[i]
        break;
        case undefined:
            //do nothing?
        break;
        default: 
            //?
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer covers it pretty much completely.

Comment: it gives me syntax error on the statment document.getElementsByClassName(class)

Comment: @user1774034 I've edited my answer: `class` is a reserved word (for possible future use), I've changed it to `classStr`. change the variable name and you should be all right. Please note that, as far as the second loop is concerned (the one with the `switch` statement) I'm assuming the array `animatorpadsIds` contains references to DOM Elements, not strings

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem it works but there is only one problem only the last statement executes eg case 'pong':
            //do something else with animateripadsIds[i]
        break;
it always executes this statement or whatever the last case is except default.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a fall-through on your hands: every `case` block has to end with either a `break;` statement or a `return` statement, if not all of the following cases will be executed, too, until a `break` or return is encountered.

Comment: @user1774034: [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaxu9/), notice the `break;` statements.

Answer (score 0):

An ID should uniquely identify an element, and as such you shouldn't have two id's on one element.

Comment: the classes are same but i have used 2 different ids eg
<div class="animateripad" id="ipad">
<div class="animateripad" id="pong">
still wrong?

Comment: You want to get all id's that have a class of "animateripad"? You confused us all then, you don't do that with `getElementByID` because that gets the element by the ID, not the class.

Comment: how can i make it right then now you understand what i am trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

**document.getElementById**

Returns a reference to the element by its ID.

**Syntax**

```
element = document.getElementById(id);
```

where

`element` is a reference to an Element object, or null if an element with the specified ID is not in the document.

`id` is a case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the element being sought

.